# Does the order of dependencies matter in Spring boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, thymeleaf, sts

Just started on **spring boot** and found out when using both **thymeleaf** and **mongoDB**, the order of the dependencies in pom file matters.

It works only if thymeleaf dependency is at the top of the Mongo dependency?

Any Explanation why?